# 3 column fluid layout using flexbox 3rd column pushing to the left

Tags: c#, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a fuild layout by using CSS flexbox property.
I'm trying to design a 3 column fluid layout yet my attempts seem to be not on point. the stylesheet is as follows.

some background information: 
I'm designing in c# ASP.NET. so my HTML has some code in it that makes it easy (for me) to have variable content with a master layout. Basically only the content changes on menu clicks and the rest stays the same throughout the website.

```
.MainContainer{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}

.ContentContainer{
width: 100%;
fill:aliceblue;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}

.header{
width: 100%;
height: 15%;
text-align: center;
border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}

.footer{
width: 100%;
height: 15%;
text-align: center;
border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
 }

.navbar{
display: flex;
width: 15%;
align-self: stretch;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
padding:2px;
margin: 10px;

min-width: 15%;

border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
 }

.content{
display: flex;
align-self: stretch;
width: 95%;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px;
text-align: justify;

min-width: 90%;
overflow:hidden;

border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}

.aside{
display: flex;
width: 15%;
align-self: stretch;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;

min-width: 15%;

border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}
```

HTML coding:

```
<div class="header">This is the Header space</div>

<div class="ContentContainer">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
        <a href="About.aspx">About</a>
        <a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
    </nav>

<%--    start of variable content--%>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
<%--    end of variable content--%>

    <div class="aside">Content Area for Latest items.</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">Tis is the Footer space</div>
```

The problem lies herein: whenever  is a somewhat empty page, it will not retain the desired width. The aside div will push as far left as it can go. 
Furthermore it looks like the header hight and footer hight doesn't take on the 15% of the screen dimensions.

Any pointers into the right direction?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Although you provided some code, you haven't created a [mcve] of your problem. Since this is mainly a `CSS` related issue, it would be best if you added some valid html markup that would allow anyone to experience the bug, as solving this does not require knowledge about the particular framework you are using to generate the markup. Make sure you also clarify the desired behavior. Unless you do that, we can't be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand, I think this is what you want:

```css
.MainContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ContentContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}

.footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
 }

.navbar{
  display: flex;
  width: 15%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding:2px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}

.content{
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}

.aside{
  display: flex;
  width: 15%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid; /*Debugging purposes*/
}
```

```html
<div class="MainContainer">
  <div class="header">This is the Header space</div>
  <div class="ContentContainer">
 <nav class="navbar">
   <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
   <a href="About.aspx">About</a>
   <a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
 </nav>
 <div class="content">
 </div>
 <div class="aside">Content Area for Latest items.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">Tis is the Footer space</div>
</div>
```